# How to restore zoom when I click on InputText on Smartphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a web page called m_index.aspx. So when a tablet or a smartphone open my page, the system redirect it on m_index.aspx page.

Now in this page, I have a div and Input text. If I try to open it with my smartphone, I can see the form correctly, but when I try to click on one of InputText, the devis apply automatically a zoom. When I hidden the keyboard, ths graphic is not restored correctly.

There is a mode to correct this functionality?

This is my page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="it"><head id="Head1">
    <!-- PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->
    <title>
    Place
</title>    
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

       var _cookieManager = new CookieManager();
       var _keyControlledControls = new KeyboardControlledControls();

       var _guiID = "0";
       var _companyName = "";
       var _applicationName = "";
       var _footerContent = "";
       var _userName = "";

       _global_CurrentComponent = ComponentsTypes.Mobile;


    </script>
</head>
<body class="mobile-IndexBody">
    <form name="frmIndex" method="post" action="./m_Index.aspx" id="frmIndex" style="height:100%;" autocomplete="off">
<div>
</div>

    <div id="layoutFill" class="skin-BodyMain">
    </div>
    <div id="mainFill" class="mobile-mainDiv-login">
        <div id="dvHeader" style="text-align: center;" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-SfondoLogo">
            <div id="LogoLogin" class="skin-LogIn-CompanyLogo"></div>
            <div id="PayoffLogin" class="skin-LogIn-CompanyMission"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="dvData" class="mobile-login">
            <div id="dvFormContainer" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-FormContainer">
                <div id="dvOmniaLogo" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-ProgramLogo"></div>
                <div id="dvNomeAziendaProgramma" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-NomeAziendaProgramma">Name</div>
                <div id="dvInputs" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-Labels">
            <div id="dvBoxes" style="text-align: center;" class="mobile-div-text">
                <div class="mobile-box-login">
                    <label class="mobile-skin-LogIn-Labels">User Name</label>
                    <input id="login_userName" name="login_userName" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-input" value="" type="textbox">

                    <label style="margin-top:5px;" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-Labels">Password</label>
                    <input id="login_password" name="login_password" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-input ReturnTriggerer" type="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="dvButton" style="text-align: center;" class="mobile-div-button">
                <div class="mobile-skin-button-login">
                    <label id="btnLogin" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-Buttons">Accedi</label>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div>
        <div id="dvFooter" class="mobile-skin-LogIn-Footer">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="loadingDiv" class="Loading" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    </div>

</body></html>
```